# Pushing to remote forcing me to undo my local hard reset

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using the git **CommandLine** for learning, as well as the **SourceTree** for visualizing the effects of various commands.

I start off fresh, make 4 changes and so make 4 commits, and push to my origin master 4 times:

```
commit a
commit b
commit c
commit d
```

I, then, issue the command `git reset --hard <initialID>` which takes me to where I started off fresh, before creating these commits.

I can see on SourceTree that I have successfully erased all my commits and reset everything hard back to the initial state.

Of course, I get a notification from SourceTree that I am now 4 commits behind the remote origin master, which is true!

Now, I try to push my current state, so that my remote is also updated; i.e. reset back to start, just like my local state now.

However, this is rejected, so I wonder if there is a special command to force-push and also erase all my commits and reset everything hard back to the initial state on my **remote**?

*p.s.* Obviously, when I take SourceTree's advice and pull again, I am back to my latest 4 commits situation; meaning this un-does my hard reset, so I should not pull, but try to push my current fresh state up onto the remote, so my hard reset is reflected on the remote as well, but how do I do this?

Comment: How about `git push -f origin HEAD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is very good about giving you helpful error messages most of the time, I just reproduced your example locally and I was presented with

```
! [rejected]  

error: failed to push some refs to {myRepo}
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind 
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again. 
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

'git push --help' then brings up the documentation for 'git push' (containing a lot of useful information!) including documentation on the --force flag

> **-f**
> **--force**
> Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. Also, when --force-with-lease option is used, the command refuses to update a remote ref whose current value does not match what is expected.
>
> This flag disables these checks, and can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.
>
> Note that --force applies to all the refs that are pushed, hence using it with push.default set to matching or with multiple push destinations configured with remote.*.push may overwrite refs other than the current branch (including local refs that are strictly behind their remote counterpart). To force a push to only one branch, use a + in front of the refspec to push (e.g git push origin +master to force a push to the master branch). See the < refspec>... section above for details.

Answer (score 0):

Do force (-f) push.

**Note:** the command is dangerous, it will replace your remote master's commit history with your local master's commit history.

```
$ git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Do we have a similar command for force-pulling from a remote (`origin master`) that has been reset to a previous commit? I tried `git pull -f` but does not update a local copy of the repo that has been rewinded. My problem before was to force push my local rewinding onto a remote, but now I wonder how to force pull from the same remote onto a different local that has to be updated to reflect the reseting of the remote...

Comment: Hard reset your local branch with a remote branch by `git fetch`, `git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>`

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.